# Boolean operation in graphs

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the difference between the Boolean operation (OR, AND, XOR, NXOR) and the operation ( union, intersection, substantiation) in graphs.

Comment: "substantiation" ???

Comment: And what about [Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Graph) ?

Comment: In general, for a math objects o structures $A$ and $B$ defined in terms of *sets* we have that e.g. $x \in (A \cup B)$ iff $x \in A$ OR $x \in B$, and the same with $\cap$ and AND.

Comment: substantiation, i mean the difference A-B that contains the element in B but not in A

Comment: A graph represent in matrix and defined these operator in it

Comment: I'm not sure that [substantiation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/substantiation) will fit for [(set) difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)).